# Removing letters in string at positions that don't correspond to numbers in range in list Python

Tags: python, string, list, split, character

I have a list of ranges of numbers i.e. `[[1, 3, 'C'], [4, 48, 'S'], [49, 54, 'C'], [55, 79, 'S'], [80, 83, 'C'], [84, 115, 'S'], [151, 152, 'C'], [153, 304, 'S'], [305, 305, 'D']].`

I have a sequence of characters:

`"MSEVTRSLLQRWGASLRRGADFDSWGQLVEAIDEYQILARHLQKEAQAQHNNSEFTEEQKKTIGKIATCLELRSAALQSTQSQEEFKLEDLKKLEPILKNILTYNKEFPFDVQPIPLRRILAPGEEENLEFEEDEEGGAGAGPPDSFSARVPGTLLPRLPSEPGMTLLTIRIEKIGLKDAGQCIDPYITVSVKDLNGIDLTPVQDTPVASRKEDTYVHFNVDIELQKHVERLTKGAAIFFEFKHYKPKKRFTSTKCFAFMEMDEIKPGPIVIELYKKPTDFKRKKLQLLTKKPLYLHLHQSLHKE"`

and the numbers in the list correspond to the positions of the characters.

i.e. `[1,3,'C']` means characters MSE (characters at position 1-3) are C.

Some of the characters in the string aren't being referenced by numbers in the list i.e. 116-150 aren't being referenced, and as a result I would like to remove these letters from the string.

Another example is when I have the range of numbers:`[[45, 45, 'D'], [46, 49, 'C'], [50, 66, 'S'], [67, 101, 'C'], [102, 103, 'S'], [104, 106, 'C'], [107, 108, 'S'], [109, 120, 'C'], [121, 121, 'S'], [122, 123, 'C'], [124, 140, 'S'], [141, 149, 'C'], [150, 176, 'S'], [177, 178, 'C'], [179, 181, 'S'], [182, 194, 'C'], [195, 213, 'S'], [214, 217, 'C']]`

This example is corresponding to a string of length 310, and we can see that the characters at position 0-45 are not being referred to, neither are the characters from 218-310 so I would like to remove these too.

I am having trouble creating a function that fixes these three cases of removal, as sometimes only one of the cases is true, or neither of them are true.

I have extracted the digits from the sequence into a list and changed the index as string index starts at 0:

`[44, 44, 45, 48, 49, 65, 66, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 108, 119, 120, 120, 121, 122, 123, 139, 140, 148, 149, 175, 176, 177, 178, 180, 181, 193, 194, 212, 213, 216]`

and my current thought process is:

1) If first number in list != 0, remove from corresponding character from 0 to element at first position - i.e. remove 0 to 45 in example 2.

2) If the difference between every 2nd and 3rd element != 1, i.e. if there is a gap in the middle of the numbers, then remove the letters corresponding to said elements. i.e. remove 116-150 mentioned above in example 1.

I am doing this by splitting the string into 0 to 116 and 150 to end of list and then concatenating the strings.

3) If the last number in the list is not the last character in the string, then remove from last character referenced until the end of the string.

I have tried implementing the above logic, and it works for some cases but not for others.

I have also tried adding the complete list of numbers into a list (i.e) the range of each pair of numbers, and removing the characters at the positions not referenced in list.

#### x is the list of numbers, strSeq is the string

```py
copyx = x
x[0]=0

veryFirstElementOfX = int(x[0])
veryLastElementOfX = int(x[-1])

removed = 0
reeString = ''

if x[0] != 0:
    for i in range(0, x[0]):
        reeString = strSeq[x[0]:]
xMinusFirst = x
xMinusFirst.pop(0)
```

```py
firstElement = int(x[0])
secondElement = int(x[1])

while secondElement != x[-1]:
    x.pop(0)
    x.pop(0)
    firstElement = int(x[0])
    secondElement = int(x[1])
    difference = secondElement - firstElement
    print("FE: " + str(firstElement))
    print("SE: " + str(secondElement))
    print(difference)
    print("\n")

    if difference > 1:
        firstString = strSeq[0:firstElement]
        secondString = strSeq[secondElement:]
        reeString = reeString + firstString + secondString
        removed = removed + (difference-1)

indexuno = veryFirstElementOfX
print(indexuno)
indexdos = veryLastElementOfX - removed
string1 = reeString[indexuno:indexdos]
```

I expect the output of a reduced string, with only the letters corresponding to the ranges of numbers in the list. 
(i.e.) the characters whose position is not being referenced removed.

The above code works with the first example (i.e.) when characters at position 116-150 need to be removed.

But when I run the code for the second sequence, I get the following error:

```
      7     x.pop(0)
      8     firstElement = int(x[0])
----> 9     secondElement = int(x[1])
     10     difference = secondElement - firstElement
     11     print("FE: " + str(firstElement))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Easier way to go about it is setting your list of numbers to a set, and subtracting from a generated set that matches the 'expected' numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding what to delete, you could create a new string with what you want to keep.

```
s = "MSEVTRSLLQRWGASLRRGADFDSWGQLVEAIDEYQILARHLQKEAQAQHNNSEFTEEQKKTIGKIATCLELRSAALQSTQSQEEFKLEDLKKLEPILKNILTYNKEFPFDVQPIPLRRILAPGEEENLEFEEDEEGGAGAGPPDSFSARVPGTLLPRLPSEPGMTLLTIRIEKIGLKDAGQCIDPYITVSVKDLNGIDLTPVQDTPVASRKEDTYVHFNVDIELQKHVERLTKGAAIFFEFKHYKPKKRFTSTKCFAFMEMDEIKPGPIVIELYKKPTDFKRKKLQLLTKKPLYLHLHQSLHKE"

L = [[1, 3, 'C'], [4, 48, 'S'], [49, 54, 'C'], [55, 79, 'S'], [80, 83, 'C'],
     [84, 115, 'S'], [151, 152, 'C'], [153, 304, 'S'], [305, 305, 'D']]

new_s = ''

for item in L:
    new_s += s[item[0]-1:item[1]]



print(len(new_s), new_s)
```

Comment: @RebeccaLenhan Do you mean you don't know how to [append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-22) an item to a list?

Comment: @Rebecca Lenihan I have no experience with dataframes so can't help you there. Maybe you could post a new question showing how far you have progressed with a sample of the dataframe you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is written a little bit confusing, but hopefully, the code below will give you some assistance or at least some ideas on how you can use `sets` in your logic to make your life much easier.

```py
list_numbers = [
    [1, 3, "C"],
    [4, 48, "S"],
    [49, 54, "C"],
    [55, 79, "S"],
    [80, 83, "C"],
    [84, 115, "S"],
    [151, 152, "C"],
    [153, 304, "S"],
    [305, 305, "D"],
]

# Generate a list of all the numbers given.
numbers = set()
for obj in list_numbers:
    num1 = obj[0]
    num2 = obj[1]
    numbers.update(range(num1, num2 + 1))

# > {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305}
print(numbers)

# Retrieve the biggest number.
max_number = max(numbers)

# Generate a set from 0 to max_number.
all_numbers = set(i for i in range(max_number))

# > {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304}
print(all_numbers)

# Subtract our current list minus the set.
missing_numbers = all_numbers - set(numbers)

# > {0, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127}
print(missing_numbers)
```

If I understood your prompt right, with the list above you should be able to remove all the indexes in the string that is not mentioned.

Comment: I see what you're doing, but the issue is that e.g. [1,3,'C'] is a range, it is referring to positions 1-3 so 1, 2 and 3 included, or [153, 304, 'S'] means numbers 153,154, 155...302,303,304 included. But you see that [84,115,'S'], [151,152,'C'] the numbers from 116 to 150 are missing. So I want to remove the corresponding characters.

Comment: Ah, understood. Code has been updated above, check it out.

Comment: 3 is being removed as is 115, but I want to keep these included. So it should for example remove 116 to 150 only. And also, the string length is 310, so from 218 to 310 is also missing, so how would I include this case? Thanks

Comment: It's fixed, my apologies. Refresh the page.

Comment: Specifically this line `numbers.update(range(num1, num2))` was fixed to `numbers.update(range(num1, num2+1))`. It happens that `print(set(range(1, 3)))` prints `{1, 2}`, so therefore the `+1` fixes.

Comment: If `0` is not supposed to be included, simply change the number generator `all_numbers = set(i for i in range(max_number))` to `all_numbers = set(i for i in range(1, max_number))`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! So the string length for this sequence is 310, so from 218 to 310 is missing, how do I include this case?

Comment: I would personally create a function that accepts a string. This way, you can take the `len(str)` and on the line `max_number = max(numbers)` simply replace the `numbers` to the `len(str)`. You can then have the function return the `set` of missing numbers, or perhaps the `list` by simply doing `list(missing_numbers)`.

Comment: Ofc, no problem. Glad to be of help.